# Nexus Content Selector not working as expected

Tags: devops, nexus

I am trying to use Content Selector to create access for a customer to my private composer repositories (using this [plugin](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-composer)).

Here is my content selector:

```
format == "composer" and path =~ "/vendor/|/vendor/package-name/.*"
```

When I test it with the UI I get my packages:

[Content Selector test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3eus.png)

But when I do a `composer require vendor/package-name` I get this error:

> Invalid credentials for 'https://nexus.company.com/repository/composer-private-packages/packages.json', aborting.

If I replace my Content Selector by:

```
    format == "composer"
```

Everything is working!

Comment: It seems you need to add `/packages.json` to your content selector since this is the file composer is trying to load and is not allowed to

Comment: Oh man, thank you! It's been a few hours I struggle with that!. It works with that rule: `format == "composer" and path =~ "^packages.json|/.*/vendor/package-name.json"`